# Evaluating Salesforce Exchange App - FilesConnect

Tags: security, appexchange, google-apps

I found what looks to be a very new app (release date - 11/24/2022) on the AppExchange and I want to know if there's a good way to do due diligence before downloading. There are no reviews besides from the company, but the product seems to be really good almost too good to be true for being free. Thank you.

App - https://www.filesconnectapp.com/

Answer (score 0):

You should install it into a sandbox to see that it meets all your technical requirements, and speak to the vendor about non-technical details such as pricing, licensing, etc.